# Delete multiple emty xml records?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how I delete multiple xml "records" if there is no attributes?

Here is what I have tried untill now:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->loadXML('<friends>
  <friend id="779">
    <name>ML76</name>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="131">
    <name>Puttepigen67</name>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="17">
    <name>rikkelolk</name>
    <games>3</games>
    <wins>2</wins>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
</friends>');

echo "<xmp>OLD \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$opNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('friend');
$remove = array();

foreach ($opNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->attributes() == ""){
        $remove[] = $node;
    }
}

foreach ($remove as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo "<xmp>NEW \n". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

I don't get anything in the last XML->saveXML().

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xpath`.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->loadXML('<friends>
  <friend id="779">
    <name>ML76</name>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="131">
    <name>Puttepigen67</name>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="17">
    <name>rikkelolk</name>
    <games>3</games>
    <wins>2</wins>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
  <friend id="">
    <name/>
    <games/>
    <wins/>
  </friend>
</friends>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

// prepare the xpath query to find the empty nodes
$node = $xpath->query("//friend[@id='']");

// if found, append the new "value" node
if( $node->length ) {
    foreach ($node as $n) {
        $n->parentNode->removeChild( $n );
    }
}
header('content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh yes... Didn't see that. Thanks :-)